# Trouble with large query in MySQL, select if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I have such a big query in my MySQL server:

```
SELECT IF(MBRContains(GeomFromText("POLYGON((37.5426344872 55.7108342622), (37.6080245972 55.7395383327))"), PointFromText(AsWkt(`map_position`))) = 1, id, NULL) as `result` FROM `webgl-app`.shapefiles_data;
```

It returns such a result:

[image]

I need to get all rows ( * ) only from the existed values.

So, the idea is: To get all records, if the data `IS NOT NULL` here.

I've tried to use:

```
SELECT IF(MBRContains(GeomFromText("POLYGON((37.5426344872 55.7108342622), (37.6080245972 55.7395383327))"), PointFromText(AsWkt(`map_position`))) = 1, id, NULL) as `result` FROM `webgl-app`.shapefiles_data WHERE `result` != NULL;
```

But it's a wrong idea, how can I fix my issue and build correct SQL query for my aim?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Alias does not work in `where` clauses. 2. compare `null` with the `IS` operator

Comment: @Strawberry `it` what?

Comment: Just curious... under what circumstances would `result` be NULL? Oh and i guess you could also use HAVING result IS NULL but I think juergen d's solution is better.

Comment: @Strawberry the result would be because of IF() statement, in my SQL code I've provided `IF(statement, result NULL)`, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `webgl-app`.shapefiles_data 
WHERE IF(MBRContains(GeomFromText("POLYGON((37.5426344872 55.7108342622), (37.6080245972 55.7395383327))"), 
       PointFromText(AsWkt(`map_position`))) = 1, id, NULL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for a great answer! May I pay your attention a bit more?
In your sample, you are taking all records, which are acceptable for this statement, but if I want to get not only id, but all data, what shoud I do?

I think, that there must be a subquery in such situation: "PointFromText(AsWkt(`map_position`))) = 1, id, NULL)", instead of `id` I can imagine to use some `SELECT ALL`, but I don't know SQL well... thanks

Comment: `select *` selects all columns of a table if you mean that.

Comment: no I meant how to inserst `select *` in this query instaed of fetching id only. I want to select all fields, not just an id using such a statement with IF and else in SQL query, which is in your answer.

Comment: I added that to the query. `select *, ...`

Comment: thanks a lot :) Also I've suggested an edit to yours answer, check it :)